# procedure does not know custom type

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having a procedure and some custom types to pass some data to it:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList AS TABLE
(Value NVARCHAR(255));

GO

CREATE TYPE KeyValueList AS TABLE
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
Value NVARCHAR(255));

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE 
#update_AttributeFormel(
    @modelPrefix NVARCHAR(255), 
    @definitionNeutralName NVARCHAR(255), 
    @newFormula NVARCHAR(255),
    @providersToRemove StringList READONLY,
    @providersToAdd KeyValueList READONLY)
    AS  ....
```

The ManagementStudio does not show any error (as it would when i comment out the type declaration) but when i execute the script, i'm getting the following errors:

```
Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure #update_AttributeFormel, Line 2
Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type StringList.
Parameter or variable '@providersToRemove' has an invalid data type.
Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure #update_AttributeFormel, Line 2
Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type KeyValueList.
Parameter or variable '@providersToAdd' has an invalid data type.
```

Implementation as explained here:

1. http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/
2. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is due to creating the procedure in the tempdb space, using **CREATE PROCEDURE `#update_AttributeFormel`**.  See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/273b0/2/0) where it is working perfectly when the types and the procedure are in the same database.

The code is replicated below:

```
CREATE TYPE StringList AS TABLE
(Value NVARCHAR(255));
GO

CREATE TYPE KeyValueList AS TABLE
(
Id uniqueidentifier,
Value NVARCHAR(255));
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE update_AttributeFormel(
    @modelPrefix NVARCHAR(255), 
    @definitionNeutralName NVARCHAR(255), 
    @newFormula NVARCHAR(255),
    @providersToRemove StringList READONLY,
    @providersToAdd KeyValueList READONLY)
AS
SELECT * FROM @providersToRemove
GO

declare @SL StringList;
insert @SL select 'abcdef' union all select 'ok';
declare @KVL KeyValueList;

exec update_AttributeFormel null,null,null,@SL,@KVL;
```

Comment: Ah makes sence! Is there a way to create something like a temporary type?

Comment: We decided to do not create temp procedures but stored procedures and drop them (and the types also) in the end of the migration process. But i think your answer was correct. Thank you!

Comment: Bonus: The user defined types appear specific to the schema within the database, not just the database itself.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create the custom data type in tempdb for it to be recognized in a different database.